# Replacement for 52 tooth chainring Ultegra triple ( 6503 ) 9 speed

Tags: shimano, chainring

Hello It seems that the stock 52t chainring for a road triple ultegra 9 speed is on  back-order or has been discontinued. Is there a replacement that will fit and shift? 
This is for my wifes Trek and she is not one to be told " Just baby it a little on the up shift "  Thanks in advance for any and all help in this matter.

Comment: I can think of two options, neither one perfect. You could look at the Tiagra 4500 series. This is obviously a step down from Ultegra but on the plus side, this range was 9-speed and was current up until a couple of years ago, so you should hopefully still be able to source parts (and they'll be interchangeable with 9-speed Ultegra). Alternatively the 6600 chainrings should fit - it won't be perfect because the 10-speed chain is narrower than the 9-speed chain, but it should be workable. I leave this as a comment in case someone can think of something better.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to replace your chainring this with any 9 or 10 speed chainring that is 110 BCD (which is the Bolt Circle Diameter for the spider on an ultegra triple crankset).

Tiagra/105/ultegra replacement rings should all fit, as well as most 3rd party manufacturers replacement rings.  Make sure the ring you want to use as a replacement has ramps and pins so that it will work as well as the original.  Stick with shimano parts to be sure of the best performance with the ultegra drivetrain.

Comment: According to http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/FC/EV-FC-6503-1702A_v1_m56577569830611836.pdf , it should be 130mm BCD for outer and middle, 74 mm BCD for inner on a Ultegra 6503 30t/42t/52t triple. So you should need a 52t, 130 bcd 5-bolt chainring.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that the 6603-52T, made for the 10-speed Ultegra, works just fine on the 9-speed triple. BCD was 130.